# oAuth 2 with Open API

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to authorize a console app to an API that uses oAuth 2.0. I've tried DotNetOpenAuth with no success.

First step is to get the Authorization code, this is what I have but I cannot find the authorization code to proceed to step 2 (Authorization using pre-defined authorization code, with User ID and User password). I have used the following authorization headers from the documentation 
https://sandbox-connect.spotware.com/draftref/GetStartAccounts.html#accounts?

In the response I do not get any headers with authentication code, how can I solve this?

```
string sAuthUri = "https://sandbox-connect.spotware.com/oauth/v2/auth";
 string postData ="access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=7_5az7pj935owsss8kgokcco84wc8osk0g0gksow0ow4s4ocwwgc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spotware.com%2F&response_type=code&scope=accounts";

        string sTokenUri = "https://sandbox-connect.spotware.com/oauth/v2/token";

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sAuthUri);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {

            using (Stream s = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                    sw.Write(postData.ToString());
            }

            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            var return = response; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Auhtorization code flow of OAuth2, the code should come in the query string of the redirection to redirect_uri.

I think that the problem is in the call method (should be GET), with postData as QueryString, and the redirect_uri must be a url of your system (not spotware). The authorization code should  be retrieved from query string of the webResponse.

I recommend you to use DotNetOpenAuth library to implement OAuth2 requests easily.